# OpenOffice launcher icon name is "untitled 1 - OpenOffice Writer"

Tags: 16.04, launcher, openoffice.org

I locked the icon to the launcher while Writer was running, and ever since it has been called "untitled 1 -OpenOffice Writer".

I think this is going to confuse me when working with several documents. Is there any way to change it to either OpenOffice or OpenOffice Writer?

Comment: Have you tried unlocking it from the launcher and then repinning it from dash Home?

Comment: It is Openoffice

Comment: @ anonymous2 : yes, I have tried unlocking it and repinning it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.

Somehow a local `.desktop` file of must have been created, with a weird naming. The local one will overrule the global one as long as it exists.

#### How to solve

1. Unlock the current `Openoffice-Writer` -launcher (icon) from the Unity-Launcher
2. Remove the local copy of the launcher: Navigate to `~/.local/share/applications` (`~` stands for your home- directory, `.local` is a directory in your home directory, hidden by default. To make it visible: in nautilus, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to make it visible). Remove any reference to `OpenOfficeWriter`.
3. Log out/in, open Dash, type "writer" and drag the icon from Dash on to the launcher.

That should solve it.

Comment: in .local there is just one file with the name "openoffice_4_1_2.desktop". Should I delete it?

Comment: @1kb if you didn't deliberately create it, and you installed OpenOffice globally (I can't imagine you didn't), you can safely delete it. It is a copy of the global one.

Comment: Ok, that worked. Cool!

Comment: @1kb Ah, that always makes me happy!